# Arrows with azimuth along line in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, style

Is it possible to make a style for the line, with arrows in the direction of digitized lines?

No coding after digitization. This is possible when I explode lines to a segments, and I made azimuth field, and then rotate the arrow simbol with azimuth, but I do not want to explode lines.

[image]

This screenshot is from another GIS program.

Comment: you should be able to use Marker Line Style? As per [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/199498/55203).

Comment: Thank you Steven, I used default arrow simbol (arrow pointing upward) and I had wrong result. I made SVG arrow and that is ok.